# Yandex Map серверная кластеризация по координатам

Tags: yandex-maps-api

На основе готового решения по серверной кластеризации: ( https://github.com/dimik/geohosting-server ), которое принимает координаты области в виде titles мне нужно сделать, чтобы сервер принимал не titles, а обычные GPS координаты области.
Предпринимал попытки преобразовать координаты в titles - ничего не вышло: (coordinatesToGlobalPixels, coordinatesToTileNumber, coordinatesToQuadKey) - в результате этих конвертаций получал либо 1 title либо несколько сотен миллионов titles в области 50x50км.

У кого есть опыт работы с Yandex Maps, помогите, пожалуйста, с этой проблемой, не смогу найти адекватных примеров и документации.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю суть вопроса, то на фронте вы должны использовать JS API Яндекса с RemoteObjectManager в главной роли. При этом документация и так позволяет выбрать координаты углов для запроса - %b – заменяется на массив географических координат углов области. https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/remote-object-manager/frontend.html#manager-creating Зачем что-то куда-то конвертировать?

Comment: клиент отдает bbox в виде координат, а сервер принимает только titles.

Comment: Тогда может проще на клиенте переписать запросы в нормальный вид? Всё равно же с карты bbox получает. Или там и клиент без JS-карты левый какой-то? И чисто для справки: это тайлы (tiles), не тайтлы (titles).